# $X$ standard normal. $Y=X^2$. Find the pdf of $Y$ and covariance between $X$&$Y$

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X$ be standard normal random variable, i.e., $X ∼ N(0, 1)$. Consider transformed random
variable: $Y = X^2$.

(a) Find the probability density function of $Y$.

(b) Find the covariance between $X$ and $Y$.

I'm new to probability and don't really get yet transformation of random variables. If anyone could help me with this one I'd much appreciate.

My work: $F_Y(y)=P(Y\leq y)=P(X^2\leq y)=P(X\leq\sqrt{y})=F_X(\sqrt{y})=\int_{-\infty}^\sqrt{y}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-t^2/2}\,dt$ that's where I'm stuck.

Edit: Is the correlation 0 because of the odd-moments popping in the equation?

Comment: BTW your $Y$ is somewhat well-known -- it is the chi-squared distribution with 1 degree of freedom.  You can read more about it on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution and verify your pdf and cdf answers.  Also $Cov(X,Y) = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]$ should easily answer part (b).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are close on the CDF. The only issue is that you need an absolute value: $$ F_Y(y) = P(|X|\le \sqrt{y}) = P(X\le \sqrt{y})-P(X\le -\sqrt{y}) = F_X(\sqrt{y})-F_X(-\sqrt y).$$ This would be an integral $\int_{-\sqrt y}^{\sqrt y}$ instead of $\int_{-\infty}^{\sqrt{y}}.$

In order to get the PDF, you differentiate the CDF. This can either be done from the integral using the fundamental theorem of calculus and the chain rule, or, equivalently, using the chain rule and the fact that $f_X=F_X'.$ So you have $$ f_Y(y) = \frac{d}{dy}(F_X(\sqrt y)-F_X(-\sqrt{y}) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}(f_X(\sqrt{y})+ f_X(-\sqrt{y})) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}\frac{e^{-y/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$$ for $y>0$.

Comment: thanks! How about covariance?

Comment: @ZukoHuanyo The covariance can be computed as $$E(XY)-E(X)E(Y) = E(X^3)-E(X)E(X^2)=\;?.$$

Comment: where does the $\frac{1}{2\sqrt y}$ come from in the PDF equation?

Comment: @Elliot The chain rule